# matplotlib.units.ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: NaT

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the following time-series data and draw some vertical lines based on the first date and last date. If there is any NA I am getting an error. I would like to run the code without any error but keeping NA values in the Date column.

data

```
Date       Result
2017-01-06     0.0
2017-01-07     1.0
2017-01-08     0.0
2017-01-09     0.0
2017-01-010    0.0
NA    0.0
```

code

```
first = '2017-01-06'
last = 'NA'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(data['Date'], data['Result'], linestyle='-',color='midnightblue' ,lw=6, width=0.3)
ax.axvline(pd.to_datetime('first'), color='red', zorder=1, linestyle='--', lw=8)
ax.axvline(pd.to_datetime('last'), color='red', zorder=1, linestyle='--', lw=8)
figure = fig.savefig(result, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: why not do a `df = df.dropna()` or fill those missing rows (eg interpolate)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to keep those NA's.

Comment: OK, what would a NaT look like on a plot?

Comment: `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)` will convert it to `NaT`

Comment: @cs95 NaT shouldn't be in the plot at all or with no color.

Comment: So, can't you just drop NaT for the purpose of plotting? Not sure I understand what's preventing you from that?

Comment: @cs95 In the real scenario, the date is actually a parameter that I provide to a script while running from a command line. Often times, I  provide some specific dates with no problem. But sometimes I have no dates to provide to the script and it throws an error. It was hard for me to explain this as a question. Therefore posted a simple example.

Comment: add a `try-except` block to your code

Comment: I want to plot the data even when there is NA, it is just that there won't be a `vline`. Does try-except do this?

Comment: Yes, you can put that line in the try-except block to catch the exception.

Comment: Great! thank you. That works perfectly.